# Matrix term for all combinations of a set

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

I am attempting to apply matrix concepts to a problem I am solving. I was wondering if I am missing a specific type of matrix that fulfills the following criteria. The matrix finds all possible combinations of two parameters, $s$ and $i$. Here is how I have laid it out.

$\mathbf{J}$ is a $1 \times j$ matrix where $j$ is the number of columns, set $\mathbb{S} = x \in \{0,\dotsc,s- 1\}$,  $s$ is the set size, and $x$ is a specific element in the set.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & \dotsm & x_j
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So if $s=2$, $\mathbb{S}=x\in\{0,1\}$

I.e. random $x$ combination where $j = 6$ and $s=2$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0_1 & 1_2 & 0_3 & 1_4 & 1_5 & 1_6
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Specific combination where $x=0$ and $n=6$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0_1 & 0_2 & 0_3 & 0_4 & 0_5 & 0_6
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$\mathbf{I}$ is an $i \times 1$ matrix where $i$ is the number of rows ($s^j$), representing total rows for all combinations:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1_1 \\
\vdots \\
1_i
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$\mathbf{X}$ is $\mathbf{I} \times \mathbf{J}$, an $i \times j$ matrix representing all combinations of $\mathbb{S}$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0_{11} & \dotsm & 0_{1j} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
(s-1)_{i1} & \dotsm & (s-1)_{ij}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Another way to think of this is a matrix of matrices where the rows are matrices of potential combinations:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0_1 & \dotsm & 0_j
\end{bmatrix}_1 \\
\vdots \\
\begin{bmatrix}
(s-1)_1 & \dotsm & (s-1)_j
\end{bmatrix}_i
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I.e.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0_{11} & 0_{12} \\
0_{21} & 1_{22} \\
0_{31} & 2_{32} \\
1_{41} & 0_{42} \\
1_{51} & 1_{52} \\
1_{61} & 2_{62} \\
2_{71} & 0_{72} \\
2_{81} & 1_{82} \\
2_{91} & 2_{92} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
j=2,s=3 \therefore i=9
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0_1 & 0_2
\end{bmatrix}_1 \\
\begin{bmatrix}
0_1 & 1_2
\end{bmatrix}_2 \\
\begin{bmatrix}
1_1 & 0_2
\end{bmatrix}_3 \\
\begin{bmatrix}
1_1 & 1_2
\end{bmatrix}_4
\end{bmatrix} \\
j=2,s=2 \therefore i=4
$$

Is there a term for such a matrix or an easier way of noting this?

EDIT: I have redefined some terms.

Comment: I find this very hard to understand in spite of the examples.

Comment: I am unable to understand the question to such an extent that I don't even know what needs clarification.

Comment: @Servaes I understand the question this way: the matrix representing all combinations was constructed  - the question is about its name..

Comment: I have edited the question. @Widawensen is correct. I am also curious if there is a better way to notate the matrix.